# How to use tt_content.uid when outputting a field with inline type in TypoScript Typo3-11.5?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-11.x

I have created a countries plugin that extends tt_content. In setup.typoscript I output the fields like this:

```
tt_content.countries {
    fields {
        content {
            fields {

                countries_text1 = TEXT
                countries_text1 {
                    field = countries_text1
                }

                countries_text2 = TEXT
                countries_text2 {
                    field = countries_text2
                }

                countries_repeater = COA
                countries_repeater {
                    10 = CONTENT
                    10 {
                        table = tx_countries_domain_model_repeater
                        select {
                            selectFields = title,country
                            pidInList.field = pid
                            where = parent_table='tt_content' AND parent_uid=422
                            orderBy = sorting
                        }
                        renderObj = COA
                        renderObj {
                            10 = TEXT
                            10 {
                                field = title
                                htmlSpecialChars = 1
                                wrap = {"title": "|"###BREAK###

                            }
                            20 = TEXT
                            20 {
                                field = country
                                htmlSpecialChars = 1
                                wrap = "country": "|"}###BREAK###
                            }
                        }
                        stdWrap.split {
                            token = ###BREAK###
                            cObjNum = 1 |*|2|*| 3
                            1 {
                                current = 1
                                stdWrap.wrap = [|
                            }
                            2 {
                                current = 1
                                stdWrap.wrap = ,|
                            }
                            3 {
                                current = 1
                                stdWrap.wrap = |]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it works. It outputs what I need, but only for the specified parent_uid=422. Can you tell me how I can replace "422" with the uid from the tt_content table?

I have tried parent_uid=current:uid, parent_uid=###data.uid### and parent_uid=###uid### with data = current:uid. But all options return an error.

Appreciate any hints you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypoScript has the [`marker`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/12.4/en-us/Functions/Select.html#markers) property below `select`, with which you can insert a value (and use full *stdWrap* properties) in a `WHERE` clause.

```
select {
    selectFields = title,country
    pidInList.field = pid
    where = parent_table='tt_content' AND parent_uid=###parentUid###
    markers {
        parentUid.field = uid
    }
    orderBy = sorting
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It didn't break the output, but unfortunately I couldn't get the results. Here is the output as it turns out (if parent_uid=422, then countries_repeater outputs json):
`"countries_text1": "Push boundaries",
"countries_text2": "News DB",
"countries_repeater": "]"`

Comment: Maybe, the part in the `marker`-section is not correct (Haven't tested it). Perhaps `parentUid.field = uid` is, what you are needing.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really `parentUid.field = uid` helped!

Comment: You are welcome. I have corrected the TypoScript in my answer.